# Simulating a robot

Tags: robotic-arm, simulation

I try to simulate a robot, but with a GUI. I can make a simulation using pyopengl to simulate the movement of robot, but I cannot make the GUI with that. I need to make it easier to simulate, analyze, communicate and run the robot (and simulation).

My app so far :

- Using python for image processing and communication with the robot
- Using pyopengl to simulate 3D
- Using matplotlib to display the log of robot movement

Is there any advice on how to create an app that is able to simulate, analyze, communicate and run in compact design?

[image]

My current app has no button and hard to analyze.

Comment: What speaks against TKinter?

Comment: i cant put pyopengl on tkinter... if there is a way... my problem actually solved...

Comment: Or tkinter has another 3d widget?

Comment: http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/ --> PyOpenGL is interoperable with a large number of external GUI libraries for Python including (but not limited to):

    wxPython
    PyGame
    PyQt and PySide
    PyGTK
    Raw XLib
    OSMesa
    Raspberry Pi BCM
    Tkinter (if you have installed the Togl widget for Tk)

Comment: @50k4 i try to use Togl widget.. but i confused  because i cant use glpushmatrix and glpopmatrix ( i used this when creating my robot model) do you have any idea about this?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you want to do is all contained within ROS (http://www.ros.org/about-ros/). There is lots of functionality already with ROS, but it is really good for simulation, communication between hardware, etc. You can still write your codes in python, but all the things you want to do are massively simplified.

Comment: This ROS, which has produced alone in this forum 100s of questions because it's hard to install, doesn't run in Fedora, and is poorly documented?

Comment: Is ros able to create gui?

Comment: ROS can be installed on Fedora, although some packages are not available. It is possible to do though. On Ubuntu installation is very easy. There is a package for GUIs, http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2012/10/21/ros-gui or you can use Qt or some other software to create the GUI. It should interface easily with ROS.